# rosconsole: How to include file and line number in log output

Tags: ros, log4cxx, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TLDR: How can I include file name and line number in ros logging information that is sent to stdout when launching a node.

It seems like the `ROS_LOG` macros would store the file name (`__FILE__`) and line number (`__LINE__`) from where the `ROS_LOG` was used.  Is there a way to include that information in the normal output to `screen`?  I know that I can see it in `rqt_console`.

I tried to dig into how `rosconsole` uses log4cxx and only found, that `log4cxx::Logger::forcedLog(..)` is used to pass the log message to log4cxx where a `log4cxx::spi::LocationInfo` object contains the file name and line number.  I assume, I'll have to find the log4cxx *layout* that is used to generate the output printed to screen and somehow change it to make use of the file name and line number.

Could someone please help me to (a) find where this layout needs to be specified and (b) how to set it to include file name and line number?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238251/rosconsole:-how-to-include-file-and-line-number-in-log-output/) by [Michael Kopp](https://answers.ros.org/users/27206/michael-kopp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2016-06-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please refer to [wiki/rosconsole - Console Output Formatting](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Console_Output_Formatting):

> rosconsole allows you to specify how you'd like its output to show up in the console output through the `ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT` environment variable.

See the wiki page for the available options.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2